# How to set this code to automatic start after refresh page?

Tags: jquery

Someone has created this code for me and i cannot find him now to finish the code. I tried to google and asked many people, but i cannot figure out how to automatically start this code after i refresh the page.

This code works only for a specific site (not my site) and it works only when i click on `bookmark` (in bookmark is saved this code).

Please, can someone edit this or help me to autostart?

```
javascript:var progressElm=$("<div>da</div>");
$("#am_widget_Farm").before(progressElm);

var total=$(".farm_icon_a").length;
var farms=$(".farm_icon_a");

var fasend=function(a){
   if(a==total)return;
   $(farms[a]).trigger("click");
   progressElm.html(a+" / "+total);

   setTimeout("fasend("+a+"+1)",250+Math.random(150))
};
fasend(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

After "refreshing" page? I dunno.

But if you want your code executed once the page is loaded, juste add a script tag into the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var progressElm=$("<div>da</div>");
        $("#am_widget_Farm").before(progressElm);
        var total=$(".farm_icon_a").length;
        var farms=$(".farm_icon_a");
        var fasend=function(a){if(a==total)return;
        $(farms[a]).trigger("click");
        progressElm.html(a+" / "+total);
        setTimeout("fasend("+a+"+1)",250+Math.random(150))};
        fasend(0);
    });
</script>
```

The `$(document.ready(function);` is called once the entire page is loaded.

But... What does this script exactly do?

> This code work only for a specific site (not my site) ...

the script calls from elements in the page, (with ID am_widget_Farm, and some others with class farm_icon_a , so if you want it to work on your page, make sure that these elements are in place, with appropriate css.

Comment: Sorry, i try this and not works because i have to open the code only from bookmark. This code click to farm_icon_a  for ,,n,, times.

Comment: If you have "$ is not defined", include jQuery files in your <head> (before your script):
`<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Regex

Hide network messages
All
Errors
Warnings
Info
Logs
Debug
Handled

2
http://%3Cscript%20type%3D%22text/javascript%22%20src=%22//code.jquery.com/…Timeout("fasend("+a+"+1)",250+Math.random(150))}; fasend(0); }); </script> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: but what? you need to create an HTML page which contain it, not copy / paste js into bookmarks! you can't run JS directly from bookmark

Comment: My code run directly from bookmark! I try how you say by 5-6 days. Everybody say is impossible but that is the true, i can make a video or something